# Real-time updation of C3.js -- fetching from DB?

Tags: javascript, php, c3.js

**What I'm doing:**
Fetching data of tweets from MySQL using PHP; assigning the PHP output to a Javascript array; passing the JS array as a parameter to C3.js.

**Problem:**
The MySQL DB is constantly updated. So I need to update the C3 graph as well. My problem is that I'm mixing PHP and JS, so I'm not able to bundle them into the same function and call this function. **How can I fetch the fresh data from the DB and update the graph?**
Here's the code:

```
<?php
// Fetch data from DB
$sql = "SELECT created_at, COUNT(text) as tweetcounts from brexittweets group by created_at order by created_at desc limit 100";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<script>
var timeStamps = [];
var statusesCount = [];
timeStamps.push('timeStamps');
statusesCount.push('statuses');
 <?php

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // assign PHP output to JS variables
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
      timeStamps.push('<?php echo $row['created_at'];?>');
      statusesCount.push('<?php echo $row['tweetcounts'] ?>');
      console.log(timeStamps);

 <?php
}
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
</script>
<?php echo '<div id ="chart2"></div>'?>
<script>
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart2',
data: {
    x: 'timeStamps',
    xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    columns: [
      timeStamps,
      statusesCount
    ]
},
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: {
          format:'%H:%M:%S'
        }
    }
}
});
setTimeout(function () {
// Need to fetch fresh data here 
}
```

Comment: Use one function for the drawing the chart and make AJAX schedule for update data to you database table. after getting AJAX  check there is new record in table then update the graph i have already work on that so am not wrong .

Comment: Thanks Jignesh, do you have some kind of sample code to get me started?